# How to create a For_Each_With_Condition_With_Index Extension method (EM)

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have a `ForEachWithIndex` EM

```
static void ForEachWithIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enu, Action<T, int> action)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach(T item in enu)
        action(item, i++);
}
```

I call it like this

```
my_int_array.ForEachWithIndex((x, i) => x += i);
```

Now i want to create one which checks for condition and then perform that action.

Usually i use above as

```
my_int_array.ForEachWithIndex((x,i) => 
{
    if (x != 0)
        x += i;
});
```

I want a EM that takes that condition as parameter also. How to do that?

Comment: You could add predicate to your extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an additional Func parameter,  something like this:

```
public static void ForEachWithIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enu,
                           Action<T, int> action, Func<T, int, bool> condition)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (T item in enu)
    {
        if (condition(item, i))
        {
            action(item, i);
        }
        ++i;
    }
}
```

And this is what the code for your example look like:

```
my_int_array.ForEachWithIndex((x, i) => x += i, (x, i) => x != 0);
```

Comment: @Santo: "i" is a value type. Predicates can only change a **copy** of "i", not an original value!.

Comment: Dennis, you are right I was thinking on a case where an Anonymous predicate is declared and a local variable is used inside the predicate.

Answer (score 3):

I would try to avoid building one big extension method which does it all. Break it out, just like LINQ does.

Personally I wouldn't actually do *any* of this though - I'd build a query with LINQ, then use a `foreach` statement for the action:

```
// Assuming you want the *original* indexes
var query = array.Select((Value, Index) => new { value, Index })
                 .Where(pair => pair.Index != 0);

foreach (var pair in query)
{
    // Do something
}
```

It's hard to know exactly what you're trying to do, given that incrementing the lambda parameter won't really achieve anything. I *would* strongly encourage you to think of composing blocks though... and you may find [Eric Lippert's views on `foreach` vs `ForEach`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) interesting.

Comment: I personally mirror your feelings of not creating one big EM. But i can't help it. I am given a module to develop. In it even after using EM my module's lines of code are increasing day by day. What will happen if i don't use EM's.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: You'll have easier-to-maintain code, because you'll have logically separated the condition from the action?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the condition delegate to parameters list:

```
static void ForEachWithIndexWithCondition<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enu, 
                     Func<T, int, bool> condition, Action<T, int> action)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (T item in enu)
    {
        if (condition(item, i))
            action(item, i);
        i++;
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
        var list = new List<string> { "Jonh", "Mary", "Alice", "Peter" };

        list.ForEachWithIndexWithCondition(
            (s, i) => i % 2 == 0,
            (s, i) => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

Comment: Dennis I think `i` should be incremented outside action. Else it will give wrong indexes. and BTW how to call it?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, yes, you're right - in the case if condition is false, next iteration will give wrong indexes. Updated the answer.

Comment: Without usage it was a half baked answer. If usage was given before I would have accepted your answer. Still Thanks. +1 from me.